# Screen Scraping IOT Device

Tags: screen-scraping

Hello everyone and thanks for the help in advance.  I need to create a screen scrape type of application to connect to an IOT device (it is a vision screening device).  The data is easily accessible through any web browser.  When the IP address is typed in, a challenge box pops up asking for a user name and password.  My thinking was to monitor the traffic posted back, however, there doesn't appear to be any type of postback to the webserver in the device.  There is obviously some type of validation occurring, but I can't figure out how.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a great deal of searching, I finally came across Selenium web browser automation located at https://www.seleniumhq.org/.  I found I was able to logon and pull data from the device.  I never really figured out why I couldn't see the network traffic, but I resolved my problem.